# Is it possible to force some functions to use different class during testing?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have class with few methods. Let's say A

file *a.py*

```
class A:
    def foo():
        ...

    def bar():
        ...
```

during normal runtime (not testing) I use it in different modules, like that.

file *functions.py*

```
from a import A

def sample_function():
    a_instance = A()
    result = a_instance.foo()
    return result
```

But during tests I would like to replace it with different class, let's say MockA.

file *mock_a.py*

```
class MockA:
    # same methods name, but with different implementation
    def foo():
        ...

    def bar():
        ...
```

Now I would like to test module with some functionality

*tests*

```
from functions import sample_function

def test_sample_function():
    assert sample_function() == expected_output
```

The QUESTION is:

Can I somehow "globally" set alias `A = MockA` (or do this in other way), so that during tests `sample_function` use functionality from `MockA`?

Comment: What testing and/or mocking framework are you using?

Comment: @KarlKnetchel I use pytest

Comment: Okay, I added that as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sample_function` uses whatever `A` is bound to in the global namespace of the module `functions`. You can rebind your own class to that name.

```
from functions import one_function


class MockA:
    ...

functions.A = MockA


def test_sample_function():
    assert sample_function() == expected_output
```

Comment: It looks like solution. I can't try it now, but I will tomorrow and if it works, then I'll give vote up and accept.
Initially, thanku you very much :D

Comment: Note that this depends on the form of import you used: if you had written `import a`, and refernce `a.A` instead of `A` itself, this would not work. Check the `unittest.mock` module, specifically the `patch` function, for more flexible ways to patch a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [unittest.mock.patch is for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch)

How about you use:

*tests*

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from mock_a import MockA
from functions import sample_function

@patch('functions.A', new_callable=MockA)
def test_sample_function(mocked_A):
    assert sample_function() == expected_output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changeing this:

```
from a import A
```

into this:

```
from mock_a import MockA as A
```

Comment: I don't want to change anything permanentyly in *functions.py*

Answer (score 0):

First correct me in comments if I am wrong, but is it a mistake that you wrote `one_function` in your last code snippet, where you should have written `sample_function`.

I think your concern is that you don't want to change the **functions.py** code by replacing `a_instance = A()` with `a_instance = MockA()` everywhere in the code. So just make **mock_a.py** with same class name `class A:` and same methods name, but different implementations(like you said). All you will have to change in your **functions.py** code  is `from mock_a import A` instead all all instance of `class A()` to `class MockA()`. This way I think your tests should work perfectly.

Comment: Yeas, but my goal is to doesn't change anything in `functions.py`, because then I would have to change it when I want to test and change it back when I want my program to run normal, in production.

Comment: @HubertSkrzypczak, so when you want to run ```functions.py``` normally you want it to import from ```a``` module, but when running ```test.py``` which uses ```functions.py``` you want it to import from ```mock_a``` module, all that without changing a single line of code. Now I want to know if there's a way.